# Why logo and Navbar floated to left when added Bootstrap CSS file

Tags: html, css

So I added the current CDN files of Bootstrap to my code but when I did, the main navigation bar got all screwy. 
Here is what the HTML looks like:

```
 <header>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="img/whitestag.jpg">
   </div>
   <ul class="main-nav">
    <li class "active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Story</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Work</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="hero">
  <h1>Professional Full Stack Developer</h1>
  <div class="button">
  <a href="" class="btn btn-half">What Can I Do?</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-full">Completed Projects</a>
  </div>
  </div>

  </header>
```

AND here is what the CSS currently says:

```
.main-nav{
  float:right;
  list-style:none;
  margin-top:55px;
  margin-right:30px;

  }
 .main-nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:30px;
  }
 .main-nav li a{
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:90%;
  font-width:bold;
  }
  .main-nav li a:hover{
  color:#e67e22;
  border-bottom:2px #e67e22;
  transition:all 0.5s ease-in;
  padding:20px 0;
  }
  .logo img{
  height:70px;
  float:right;
  margin-top:30px;
  border-radius:12px;
   }
```

BUT the end result still looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVOhS.jpg)

Any help would be great! Totally new to this.

Comment: you should load your custom css before the `bootstrap.css` to override the bootstrap defaults

Comment: or you can use `! important` in each property that requires override